# How to layout base class and 3 extended classes in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, class, inheritance

This is the layout I'd like to use for controllers in CodeIgniter:

```
(base) editor
(extend) design
(extend) content
(extend) ...php
```

...where `editor` is a base class and `design`, `content`, etc. controllers extend `editor`. The `editor` class will have methods that are publicly accessible from the extended classes URL segments.

I've read some topics on here, and they recommended:

1. Library - this won't work as methods won't be publicly accessible (am I correct?)
2. Put base class in the same file as extended class and name the controller that - this won't work since I need to extend from multiple places.
3. Put all the files in the controllers folder, add require statements to each extended class - is this bad form?

I'm new to CI. What's the proper/correct way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html  extend the core CI controller with MY_Controller, then extend MY_Controller with your other controllers. all the other retain the functionality in MY and MY retains the functionality of the base controller

Comment: That was #3 in my list, in their docs it says using require statements (from extended controller to base controller) is bad form?

Comment: You don't need any require statements if one controller extends the next. So you have your base CI_Controller which holds all of CI's system stuff, you don't want to modify that because it changes with CI updates. So your flow is CI_Controller > MY_Controller > Other controllers, each retains the functionality of the previous, sort of like including would. Honestly I think CI adds the require in the background not positive though, I just know it works and works well for what you want.

Comment: That's what I'm using now, you do need the require statement since the base definition is in another file (error unknown class editor). Please add your response as an answer, I'm going to leave it open for a while in case someone else posts why their docs recommend not doing it this way. Otherwise I'll mark your answer correct.

Comment: Done, see the addition of the second link which I believe you'll find even more useful and it should cover your unknown class error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

extend the core CI controller with MY_Controller, then extend MY_Controller with your other controllers. all the other retain the functionality in MY and MY retains the functionality of the base controller

There is also this article which allows more controllers that don't have the MY_ prefix, which I use and find VERY useful!

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY